# How do I draw a rectangle encircling a text in jsPDF?

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I am writing a text into a pdf like this:

```
var splitTitle = doc.splitTextToSize(str, 180);
doc.text(15, 15, splitTitle);
```

This is the output:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyMUy.png)

What I want to do is to draw a rectangle around the text. The text height can be dynamic depending on the length of the text, so how do I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the text dimensions by using `getTextDimensions()` solved the issue:

```
doc.rect(15,15,doc.getTextDimensions(splitTitle).w,doc.getTextDimensions(splitTitle).h)
```